# Error al traer información de una computadora y guardarla en otra con servidor socket Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, socket, seguridad

Hola muy buenas comunidad. Tengo dos scripts: un slave, y un server en python para hacer conexión a través de la librería socket entre dos computadores, el server esta en una maquina virtual kali linux y el slave en mi windows 10. La conexion entre las computadores se hace correctamente pero a la hora de querer traer un archivo del windows 10 al kali (mi archivo de prueba es un documento .docx) no me funciona y salta el siguiente error:

[image: no identifico si es un problema a la hora de enviar el archivo o si es un problema al crear y guardar el archivo con la data]

Con archivos .txt funciona correctamente.

Aqui está la parte de codigo del slave(windows 10):

```
elif command == 'download_file':
    try:
        userInput = s.recv(5000) #receive the instruccion
        userInput = userInput.decode()
        file = open(userInput, 'rb') #open the file especified as readable file
        fileName = str(os.path.basename(file.name)) #get name of the file with extension            
        s.send(fileName.encode()) #send file name
        data = file.read() #copy info to data var
        s.send(data) #send info
        print("\nFile has been sent successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print("error try again")
```

Y aquí está la parte de codigo del server(kali):

```
 elif command == 'download_file':   
    conn.send(command.encode()) 
    userInput = input(str(' >Set path with file and extension: '))
    conn.send(userInput.encode()) 
    fileName = conn.recv(5000) #receive the filename for create the new file with this name
    file = conn.recv(70000) #receive the file
    newFile = open(fileName, "wb") #create a file whit the original name and original extension
    newFile.write(file)#write info into the new file
    newFile.close()
    print('\n{}[{}+{}]File has been downloaded and saved'.format(Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX, Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX, Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX))
```

Comment: Imprime el nombre del archivo que recibes en `fileName = conn.recv(5000)`. Al parece trae caracteres no válidos.

Comment: @CandidMoe Al agregar la linea de código para imprimir el nombre me funciona, y me trae y me crea la el archivo con la información correctamente y al eliminar esa linea de código vuelve el error. Es muy extraño. `print(fileName)`

Comment: Creo que el nombre del archivo Windows contiene caracteres ilegales en Linux. Modifica el script Windows para que imprima el nombre del archivo y agrega eso a tu pregunta.